# Why doesn't my operation work when I use BigDecimal?

Tags: java, bigdecimal

I'm trying to do an operation using `BigDecimal` but it always return `0`. Why does it work when I use `double`?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    double a = 3376.88;
    BigDecimal b = new BigDecimal(a);
    System.out.println(a-a/1.05);
    System.out.println(b.subtract(b).divide(new BigDecimal(1.05)).doubleValue());
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: What do you think `b.subtract(b)` does?

Comment: `b.subtract(b)` is making a number subtract itself, so it's worth `0`.

Comment: Never ever initialize a `BigDecimal` with the `double` ctor. Use the `string` ctor.

Comment: What do you mean by work ?

Comment: This is a good question.  It's intuitive for us to believe order of operation is enforced.  Maybe there should be a way for `BigDecimal` to enforce it...

Comment: @CyberneticTwerkGuruOrc You could create something similar to String formatting and evaluate the string according to the order of operations. Something like `BigDecimal.evaluate("%b - %b / 1.05", b, b);` `%%` could mean the mod operator. Or perhaps `BigDecimal.evaluate("-/",b,b,new BigDecimal("1.05"));`

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are not performing the same operations.

When you are doing the double operations, the normal java order of operations is applying:

```
a-a/1.05  
= a - (a/1.05)
```

But when you are running the methods on `BigDecimal`, the operations are evaluated in the order you are calling them, so

```
b.subtract(b).divide(new BigDecimal(1.05))
```

is equivalent to

```
(b - b) / 1.05
= 0 / 1.05
= 0
```

Comment: b.subtract(b.divide(new BigDecimal(1.05), 2)

Comment: I'm not sure what a math context of '2' would mean in this case.  That doesn't even compile for me in eclipse. Can you expand your comment?

Answer (score 7):

When you chain method calls for `BigDecimal`, the order of operations is not preserved as it is in math, and as with `double` operators in Java.  The methods will be executed in order.  That means that `b.subtract(b)` happens first, resulting in the `BigDecimal` `0`.

To obtain the equivalent result, enforce the order of operations yourself by sending the result of the `divide` method to the `subtract` method.

```
System.out.println(b.subtract( b.divide(new BigDecimal(1.05)) ).doubleValue());
```